# search server c# via android application

Tags: c#, java

I have more than one servers in c# and more than one client as android applications.
I heard about Socket connection to connect both but it ask ip and port of server,
My worry is that I have to connect android application to nearest server which always vary.
then how to connect server with client where i didn't know exact ip and port of server?
Is there any other method to connect windows application and android application

Comment: I think it will help if you give an example and / or code snippet.  If you are using standard protocols, the android application doesn't really need to know the server is a windows server.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have got two questions,
1) How can you figure out what is the address of the nearest server. You will need some kind of resolution mechanism in place. One idea, depending on the number of servers, would be to keep a list of the servers addresses and just ping to see which one has the best response time.

2) How do you exchange information from an android application to a c# server? It depends on the interfaces the C# server exposes. Usually, if it was designed with inter platform communication in mind, it will provide some Web Services for you to access.